# Proper way to response to an f:ajax event from bean?

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

I have some simple methods called from `<f:ajax />` tags. I sometimes want to send back an error or some useful information.

So far to send errors I have been throwing an exception and catching the `jsf.ajax.addOnError` javascript call to handle them however I think there should be a better way. I guess I could also set bean properties but that seems like a bit of a hassle. Is there no other way of doing this?

I'm using JSF2/mojarra.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the OmniFaces ajax exception handler: 
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/full-ajax-exception-handler.html